# Calling another html template from a django template. (Database used is mongoDb)

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am starter for django.

I am creating a login page where if username/password exists in database(mongoDB). It takes it to another page.

***My template is as follows:***

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Simple Login Page</h1>
    <form name="login">
        Username<input type="text" name="userid"/>
        Password<input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
        <input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
    </form>

    <ul>
        {% for item in Employee %}


            {% if item.name == form.userid.value && item.password == form.paswd.value %} ***"""""one more check for item.field ::: if(field =="a") then take to page:1.html else take to page2.html"""*** {% else %} **Wrong password pop up**{% endif %}


            <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
                    }

    </script>
</body>
```

How can this be done in Django, mongodb, python

Comment: Do you need to redirect user to another page?

Comment: You should consider put this logic into your view, not your template..

Comment: the logic belongs in the view

Comment: I can access all user's info from database using models. How can I access form values in model before firing the render to responce . Following is my view function:                                                                def login(request):

    Emp = emp.objects()
    return render_to_response('login.html', { 'Employee' : Emp.all()})

Comment: @Ernest Ten: I wish it to redirect to another page if the user name and password exists in my DB and redirect it to different pages , depends on if it is a teacher or student.

Comment: @shalini Then you need to implement that logic in a view that handles login form.